# How to get Pojo name referenced Json object when we Jackson data-binding

Tags: java, spring, jax-rs, cxf, aegis

I am generating Rest Services using Jackson. I am able to get JSON response like

```
[{"userName":"scott","userId":7},{"userName":"toe","userId":101}]
```

but i am expecting response with Pojo name pointing to the response like below

```
{"UserDetails":[{"userName":"scott","userId":7},{"userName":"toe","userId":101}]}
```

Here is my implementation class

```
@Service("userServices")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserServices{

private UserServices userServices;

public UserServices getUserServices() {
    return userServices;
}
public void setUserServices(UserServices userServices) {
    this.userServices = userServices;
}

@Override
public List<UserDetails> getUser(UserDetails userDetails) {


    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    List<UserDetails> user = new ArrayList<UserDetails>();
    List<UserDetails> list = new ArrayList<UserDetails>();

    UserDetails userDetails2 = new UserDetails();
    userDetails2.setUserName("scott");
    userDetails2.setUserId(007);

    UserDetails userDetails3 = new UserDetails();
    userDetails3.setUserName("toe");
    userDetails3.setUserId(101);

    user.add(userDetails2);
    user.add(userDetails3);

    try{
    String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(user);
    UserDetails[] userDetails4 = mapper.readValue(jsonString, UserDetails[].class);
    list = Arrays.asList(userDetails4);
    System.out.println(userDetails4);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return list;
}
}
```

and here is my pojo

```
public class UserDetails implements Serializable{

private String userName;
private int userId;

public UserDetails(){

}

 //getters and setters...
}
```

** Note:** I don't want to use any annotations at the domain object side.

Comment: Why do you want to have that? Wat benefit does the additional field give you? I think, it's useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `objectMapper.writeValueAsString(aCustomMap)` for custom json view creation on the fly.

Example:

```
UserDetails userDetails2 = new UserDetails();
userDetails2.setUserName("scott");
userDetails2.setUserId(007);

UserDetails userDetails3 = new UserDetails();
userDetails3.setUserName("toe");
userDetails3.setUserId(101);

Map<String, List<UserDetails>> m = new HashMap<>();
m.put("UserDetails", Arrays.asList(userDetails2, userDetails3));

System.out.print(
    //This is what you need
    objectMapper.writeValueAsString(m)
);
//{"UserDetails":[{"userName":"scott","userId":7},{"userName":"toe","userId":101}]}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, when i use this i am getting compilation exception like                   Type mismatch: cannot convert from Map<String,List<UserDetails>> to List<UserDetails>

Comment: Sorry, replace the Car with your UserDetails class name. Tested a template code with a Car class.

Comment: yeah I already changed that even though it's giving same error

Comment: What is your updated code? My code is getting compiled and working. It was just a demonstration to use a map for the desired result. You have to use it according to your code requirement. Looks like you are passing this map where a List is required. Please use the map to generate the final JSON/JSON-string and not make is unnecessarily everywhere.

Comment: Map<String, List<UserDetails>> m = new HashMap<>();
  m.put("UserDetails", Arrays.asList(userDetails2, userDetails3));

  try {
   System.out.print(
       //This is what you need
       mapper.writeValueAsString(m)
   );
  } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
here i want to return the list of user details object

Comment: Change the method signature from List<UserDetails> to Map<String, List<UserDetails>>. Otherewise, it will return a list and in the final json, you cannot get the name tag "UserDetails".

Comment: Thanks for the solution it's working fine, Is there any other approach without any changes to method return type

Comment: You create the map in the controller method and not in the service method. Service method should return the list, controller method should take the decision of how to show it to the user in the API.

Answer (score 1):

Just return

UserDetailsResponse:

```java
public class UserDetailsResponse {

    private List<UserDetails> userDetails;
    // getter and setter

}
```

instead of list of UserDetails in the UserServiceImpl (and presumably then in the controller).

Comment: It's working fine but I think it's not applicable to multiple service call methods. any suggestion for this

Comment: not sure if I understand your problem correctly, but you can keep the service to return List (as you had) and then do the mapping to response object only when it leaves your application (e.g. in controller)

Answer (score 0):

You return a List of UserDetails which translates to your response object being a JSON Array. In order to get your desired result you would need to create a Container class (UserDetailsContainer) which has the property userDetails of the List type and return an instance of that as your response.